# Initialising a choice element from an XSD

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm very new to working with XSD files so need a little assistance.  I have an XSD through which I've used `XSD.exe` to create an object class.  All is fine and I'm working through initialising the created class object, but I have hit a road block.  In the XSD is a choice element, the object class for this looks as follows:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontact
{
    private object itemField;
    private object[] phoneprivateField;
    private object[] phoneofficeField;
    private object[] faxprivateField;
    private object[] faxofficeField;
    private object[] emailprivateField;
    private object[] emailofficeField;
    private object[] websiteField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("company", typeof(exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactCompany))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("person", typeof(exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactPerson))]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("phone-private")]
    public object[] phoneprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneprivateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("phone-office")]
    public object[] phoneoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneofficeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fax-private")]
    public object[] faxprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxprivateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fax-office")]
    public object[] faxoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxofficeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("e-mail-private")]
    public object[] emailprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailprivateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("e-mail-office")]
    public object[] emailoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailofficeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("website")]
    public object[] website
    {
        get
        {
            return this.websiteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.websiteField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactCompany
{
    private object nameField;
    private string phoneField;
    private string faxField;
    private string emailField;
    private string websiteField;

    public object name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    public string phone
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneField = value;
        }
    }

    public string fax
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("e-mail")]
    public string email
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailField = value;
        }
    }

    public string website
    {
        get
        {
            return this.websiteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.websiteField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactPerson
{
    private object titleField;
    private object salutationField;
    private object forenameField;
    private object surnameField;
    private System.DateTime birthdateField;
    private bool birthdateFieldSpecified;

    public object title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    public object salutation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.salutationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.salutationField = value;
        }
    }

    public object forename
    {
        get
        {
            return this.forenameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.forenameField = value;
        }
    }

    public object surname
    {
        get
        {
            return this.surnameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.surnameField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime birthdate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.birthdateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.birthdateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool birthdateSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.birthdateFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.birthdateFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So I see that the 'Item' object can have either the type `exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactCompany` or `exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactPerson` but I'm not sure how I might initialise `Item` correctly.  I imagine I will have to check it's type with `is` but I'm not completely sure. Can anyone offer some assistance or provide an example of initialisng a choice element?

Comment: You need a base class exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontact which is inherited by exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactCompany and exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactPerson

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?